# intersecting multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, intersection

let say i have 1 multidimensional array and i want to exclude values that not equal in javascript.

here is the example array.

```
var filter = ["big_number", "odds_number"];
var arrays = {
    "first" : {
        "big_number" : [50,51,52],
        "odds_number" : [39,41,51,53]
    },
    "second" : {
        "big_number" : [61,62,63,64,65,70,72,73],
        "odds_number" : [13,15,17,19,61,63,65,73]
    }
};
```

i want to convert that array to be like this.

```
var new_arrays = {
    "first" : [51],
    "second" : [61,63,65,73]
};
```

here is my code

```
var newArray = {
    "first" : [],
    "second" : []
};
for (var k in arrays){
    if (arrays.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        for(var f=0; f<filter.length; f++) {
            newArray[k].push(arrays[k][filter[f]].filter(value => -1 !== arrays[k][filter[f]].indexOf(value))));
        }
   }
}
console.log(newArray);
```

actually i could do this code

```
var newArray = {
    "first" : [],
    "second" : []
};
for (var k in arrays){
    if (arrays.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        newArray[k].push(arrays[k]["big_number"].filter(value => -1 !== arrays[k]["odds_number"].indexOf(value))));
    }
}
console.log(newArray);
```

but i need to convert it through `filter variable`.
i could not use `filter[0] and filter[1]`, because that values could change dynamically and could be more than 2 values in array.

Comment: why down vote my question?

Comment: I guess that's because you haven't shown any attempt yourself. And I personally don't see the pattern here.

Comment: @JonasWilms i have mentioned that i could done it if there were 2 arrays separated.. so should i need to put code with 2 arrays separated?

Comment: @FZs could you read the question first before you said it duplicate question?

Comment: @FZs is it clear for you for that updated question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little intersection snippet:

```
function intersect(a,b){
    b.slice()
    return a.filter(item=>{
        if(b.includes(item)){
            b.splice(b.indexOf(item),1)
            return true
        }
    })
}
```

Using that, you can do this easily:

```js
function intersect(a,b){
 b.slice()
 return a.filter(item=>{
  if(b.includes(item)){
   b.splice(b.indexOf(item),1)
   return true
  }
 })
}

var filter = ["big_number", "odds_number"];
var output={}
var arrays = {
    "first" : {
        "big_number" : [50,51,52],
        "odds_number" : [39,41,51,53]
    },
    "second" : {
        "big_number" : [61,62,63,64,65,70,72,73],
        "odds_number" : [13,15,17,19,61,63,65,73]
    }
};
for(x in arrays){
    output[x]=arrays[x][filter[0]]
    for(let i=1;i<filter.length;i++){
        output[x]=intersect(output[x],arrays[x][filter[i]])
    }
}
console.log (output)
```

Comment: you can have a look for the updated question and remove that duplicate question tag.. thanks

Comment: @WillyantoHalim I updated my answer to be dynamic.   And sorry for the duplicate mark, I can't remove that, but only you can see; simply ignore it.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through the keys and update the values using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
var arrays={"first":{"big_number":[50,51,52],"odds_number":[39,41,51,53]},"second":{"big_number":[61,62,63,64,65,70,72,73],"odds_number":[13,15,17,19,61,63,65,73]}};

for (let key in arrays) {
  arrays[key] = arrays[key]["big_number"]
                  .filter(n => arrays[key]["odds_number"].includes(n));
}

console.log(arrays)
```

If you don't want to mutate the original object then use `Object.entries` and `reduce`:

```js
var arrays={"first":{"big_number":[50,51,52],"odds_number":[39,41,51,53]},"second":{"big_number":[61,62,63,64,65,70,72,73],"odds_number":[13,15,17,19,61,63,65,73]}};

const newObject = Object.entries(arrays).reduce((r, [key, {big_number, odds_number}]) => {
  r[key] = big_number.filter(n => odds_number.includes(n));
  return r
}, {})

console.log(newObject)
```

If you have more than 2 array properties, you can do something like this: Get all the arrays using `Object.values` and then use `reduce` to run the previous code recursively

```js
var arrays = {
  "first": {
    "big_number": [50, 51, 52],
    "odds_number": [39, 41, 51, 53],
    "another_key": [41, 51, 53]
  },
  "second": {
    "big_number": [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 70, 72, 73],
    "odds_number": [13, 15, 17, 19, 61, 63, 65, 73],
    "another_key": [63, 65]
  }
};

for (let key in arrays) {
  arrays[key] = Object.values(arrays[key])
                       .reduce((a, b) => a.filter(c => b.includes(c)))
}

console.log(arrays)
```

Comment: sorry, i forget to put filter variable.. it should loop through that variable.. i have update the question..

Comment: What do you mean by `filter` variable? Instead of `arrays[key]["big_number"]`, do `arrays[key][filter[0]]` and `filter[1]` for `odds_number`

Comment: yes.. filter variable value is ["big_number", "odds_number"] and the variable could change dynamically through checkbox.. so i want to loop it through that filter variable..

Comment: Do as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: cannot use filter[0] and filter[1]. because as i mentioned it could be change dynamically. could be more than 2 values in array.. not just only big_number and odds_number

Comment: So, you'll have more than 2 arrays?

Comment: i have updated the question.. please have a look.. thanks

Comment: You still haven't mentioned if you'll have more than 2 arrays keys. If only 2 arrays `filter[0]` and `filter[1]` should work fine. Otherwise you need to loop  through each inner key and find intersection. And use that resulting intersection array with the next array

Comment: yes.. that's why  i need help about that.. sorry if the first question was not clear for you..

Comment: Can I assume all the properties in the nested object arrays to intersect? `{
        "big_number" : [50,51,52],
        "odds_number" : [39,41,51,53], "another_prop": [51,52], "yet_another":[51,32]`}`
    },

Comment: I have updated the answer to handle dynamic number of array properties. And you don't need the `filter` array as well

Comment: @WillyantoHalim Intersection is getting items common to **all** arrays. If one of them is empty, then result will be empty array. This is valid

Answer (score 0):

use `Object.entries` to get keys and values and then use `reduce`

```js
var arrays = {
  "first" : {
      "big_number" : [50,51,52],
      "odds_number" : [39,41,51,53]
  },
  "second" : {
      "big_number" : [61,62,63,64,65,70,72,73],
      "odds_number" : [13,15,17,19,61,63,65,73]
  }
};

const output =Object.entries(arrays).reduce((accu, [key, {big_number}]) => {
  if(!accu[key]) accu[key] = [];
  big_number.forEach(num => {
    if(num%2 !==0)
    accu[key].push(num);
  })
  return accu;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: sorry, i forget to put filter variable.. it should loop through that variable.. i have update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the unique values from both the arrays using `Set` and then using `filter` get only the common values.

```js
var arrays = {"first": {"big_number": [50, 51, 52],"odds_number": [39, 41, 51, 53]},"second": {"big_number": [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 70, 72, 73],"odds_number": [13, 15, 17, 19, 61, 63, 65, 73]}},
    result = Object.keys(arrays).reduce((r,k) => {
      let setB = new Set(arrays[k]["big_number"]);
      r[k] = [...new Set(arrays[k]["odds_number"])].filter(x => setB.has(x));
      return r;
    },{});
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: sorry, i forget to put filter variable.. it should loop through that variable.. i have update the question.